# Set value in ion-textarea Ionic 4

Tags: html, angular, ionic-framework, textarea, ionic4

I try to use ion-textarea instead of ion-input for make a form to modify my item. I can't set a value with ngmodel or value that are from my typescript code.

I try (textNote is the variable in my ts):

```
 ngmodel="textNote" => X
 ngmodel="textNote" value="textNote" => X
 ngmodel="textNote" value="{{textNote}}" => X
```

this kind of combination never works

This is my html

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar color="primary">
    <ion-buttons slot="start">
      <ion-back-button></ion-back-button>
    </ion-buttons>
    <ion-title>
      <h6>
        Modify Audio Text
      </h6>
    </ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>

  <ion-item>
    <ion-label color="primary" >Hour</ion-label>
    <ion-datetime display-format="HH:mm" [(ngModel)]="hour"></ion-datetime>
  </ion-item>

  <ion-item>
    <ion-label color="primary">Date</ion-label>
    <ion-datetime display-format="DD MMM YYYY" [(ngModel)]="date"></ion-datetime>
  </ion-item>

  <ion-item>
    <ion-label color="primary" position="stacked">Text</ion-label>
    <ion-textarea  type="text"  [(ngModel)]="textNote"></ion-textarea>
  </ion-item>

  <ion-button expand="block" shape="round" (click)="modifyElement()">Modify</ion-button>

</ion-content>
```

This my typescript

```
import { DatabaseService } from './../services/database.service';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-note-text-modify',
  templateUrl: './note-text-modify.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./note-text-modify.page.scss'],
})
export class NoteTextModifyPage{
  date: String;
  hour: String;  
  id:Number;
  textNote: String = "";

  constructor(private route:ActivatedRoute,private router:Router,private db:DatabaseService) { 
    this.id = +(this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id'));

    this.db.getNote(this.id).then(res=>{
      this.date=res.date;
      this.hour=res.hour;
    });
  }

  modifyElement(){
    this.db.updateNoteTimeText(this.id,this.date,this.hour,this.textNote)
    .then(_=>this.router.navigateByUrl('/tabs/note'));
  }

}
```

Comment: Hey, so what are you trying to accomplish? sorry its unclear from your question what the issue is and what exactly you want to achieve?

Comment: I guess the answer is here.
[Ionic 3 how to use textarea ngModel and default value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47330808/ionic-3-how-to-use-textarea-ngmodel-and-default-value)
It works Ionic 4 too.